# How to make continuous addition button

Tags: java, android-studio, button

Hi I am making countdown timer when on activity I have button which I set time every 5( 5,10,15..) seconds but 5 seconds are added by click.  I would like to hold this button and after for example 1 second of holding my value of seconds will be added automatically every 5 seconds.

```
public void dodawanie2(View view) {

    czasrundy=czasrundy+5;
    display2(czasrundy);
}
```

this Is my code which responsible for adding  5seconds. (czasrundy- mean time of round)